# I want to Take picture from USB Webcamera in android

Tags: android

I need to detect USB Camera.If it is detected then i need to capture Image from USB webCam Instead of default camera in android

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963897/use-usb-camera-on-android-application?lq=1